# Can I reinstall Chrome without losing data?

Tags: google-chrome

In [this](https://www.wintips.org/how-to-completely-uninstall-re-install-google-chrome/) and [this](https://www.repairwin.com/how-to-uninstall-google-chrome-completely-from-your-computer/) tutorials, they tell how to completely uninstall Chrome, and that you'll lose all data

My question is that if I already enabled sync-ing, will I be able to get data back from sync after uninstall/install?

PS: my Chrome is crashing, so I'm trying to reinstall it.

Comment: "PS: my Chrome is crashing, so I'm trying to reinstall it." Have you tried disabling addons? Or a factory reset of Chrome?

Comment: Yes;  Just backup your current Chrome user profile.

Answer (score 0):

The great thing about Chrome is that after you have connected it to your google account, you can restore all of your history, bookmarks, and data by logging in again to a new computer or installation of Chrome. However, I was not able to find any sources that would confirm if saved cookies and cache would also be restored, but those are usually unimportant.

For a guide on how to connect Chrome to your google account, follow [this guide](https://kb.nmsu.edu/page.php?id=72645).

Comment: Note that even if you've connected it to your Google account, you will lose all extension data when reinstalling Chrome, unless the extension syncs your data to your account, which many don't. You may be able to manually restore this data by copying files from your profile path, but I haven't tried this.